# adapter.Fill takes long time to run

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I have an ADO.NET code to make a server call with input parameters and return Dataset. I am using SqlDataAdapter to get data and assign it Dataset.
Here is my code

```
    public DataSet GetRecordsWithParam(string spName, Dictionary<string, dynamic> ParaArr)
    {
        try
        {
            Connection();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            cmd = new SqlCommand(spName, con);
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 300;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            if ((ParaArr != null))
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, dynamic> kvp in ParaArr)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
                }
            }
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            myAdapter.Fill(ds);              
            return ds;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

But it takes too much time to execute the line

```
 myAdapter.Fill(ds);
```

There is no problem with my procedure. While assigning the data from myAdapter to ds using Fill it takes too much time. It is a global method I am using in my project, most of the time it works fine. But only when called from this method

```
 private DataSet PayPeriodFromCountryCompany(string Country, string Company, string EmployeeType, string startDate, string EndDate, string Action)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> Dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    DBConnection DB = new DBConnection();
    DataSet _dsPayPeriod = new DataSet();
    string _strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TimesheetconnString"].ConnectionString;

    try
    {
        Dic.Add("@Country", Country);
        Dic.Add("@Company", Company);
        Dic.Add("@EmployeeType", EmployeeType);
        Dic.Add("@StartDate", startDate);
        Dic.Add("@EndDate", EndDate);
        Dic.Add("@Action", Action);
        _dsPayPeriod = DB.GetRecordsWithParam("TSTime_spTimesheetToCPS", Dic);

        return _dsPayPeriod;
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }

}
```

loading problem. It takes 1-2 minute to execute the line ' myAdapter.Fill(ds);  '.

Anyone point if there is any bug in the code. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Improve Your query performance it exactly depend to your query and count of the rows ; data reader is better than SqlDataAdapter

Comment: How long does that query take if you run in SSMS?

Comment: Less than 1 sec when I run query in SSMS @MadMyche

Comment: DataAdapter uses a DataReader under the hood, so I'm doubtful there would be a performance improvement.

Comment: Try rebuilding the indexes on the the affected tables then run your code again.